# How to query earliest date from several possibly blank date fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Given the following table:

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| ID |  date1   |   date2   |  date3   |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | 3/2/2013 | 5/6/2013  |          |
|  2 |          | 12/1/2011 | 6/5/2010 |
|  3 | 1/1/1936 | 1/5/1936  | 1/9/1945 |
|  4 | 2/1/2014 |           |          |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I want a query that returns the earliest date in each row.  At least one of the date columns will be populated.

I've tried:

```
SELECT id, 
iif(date1<date2 and date1<date3,
    date1,
    iif(date2<date1 and date2<date3,
        date2,
        date3)) as dateEarliest
FROM tbl;
```

But it seems that this only returns the correct result if `date3` is the earliest; otherwise  it returns a blank.

Comment: How does MS Access treat `<` when a NULL is involved? I would expect that to work correctly on all records which do not have any NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare against a NULL value. Use the Nz function to convert the NULLs to a value you can compare to. The syntax for Nz is: `Nz ( variant, [ value_if_null ] )`.

So you'll use something like this:

```
iif(Nz(date1,#1/1/2999#) < Nz(date2,#1/1/2999#) and Nz(date1,#1/1/2999#) < (Nz(date3,#1/1/2999#)
```

If this is being used in Access, and you know VBA, you could also create a function that returned the value you want. This may be neater as it would look like:

```
Select id, LowDate([date1],[date2],[date3]) as dateEarliest
```

Here's a function that should work for you.

```
Function LowDate(D1, D2, D3)
   D1 = Nz(D1, #1/1/2999#)
   D2 = Nz(D2, #1/1/2999#)
   D3 = Nz(D3, #1/1/2999#)
   If D1 < D2 And D1 < D3 Then
      LowDate = D1
   ElseIf D2 < D1 And D2 < D3 Then
      LowDate = D2
   Else
      LowDate = D3
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: +1 But this answer seems to imply `Nz()` always returns a string, which is misleading.

Comment: My first answer returned a date on null, but in my quick testing, it didn't like Nz([date1],#1/1/2099#), so I changed my answer. But in testing again, I see it works. Must have had a typo before.

Comment: I would like your answer even more without all those `CDates`, but that's a minor issue and not enough to discourage my upvote.  My concern is that the first paragraph may be misinterpreted to mean "Nz() only returns strings".

Comment: I got your meaning the first time, and I agree with you. I didn't like all the cdates either. Only put them in there because in my initial testing, I got errors without them. Not sure why I did, but in further testing, I see the cdates are not required. I have edited my answer back to the original.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the "best" way to do it, but one way to do it would be to unpivot your data, so that it looks something like this:

```
id  date
1   
1   3/2/2013
1   5/6/2013
2   
2   6/5/2010
2   12/1/2011
3   1/1/1936
3   1/5/1936
3   1/9/1945
4   
4   2/1/2014
```

This can be done like so:

```
SELECT id, date1 from tbl
UNION
SELECT id, date2 as date1 from tbl
UNION
SELECT id, date3 as date1 from tbl
```

(Note: I named the date field date1, since date is a reserved keyword.)

From here, you can use aggregate functions such as min:

```
select id, min(date1) as dateEarliest
from (SELECT id, date1 from tbl
UNION
SELECT id, date2 as date1 from tbl
UNION
SELECT id, date3 as date1 from tbl) unpivottbl
group by id;
```

Which will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify the `iif` statement to something like:

```
SELECT id, 
iif((date1<date2 and date1<date3) or (date1 < date2 and date3 is null) or (date1 < date3 and date2 is null),
    date1,
    iif(date2<date1 and date2<date3) or (date2 < date1 and date3 is null) or (date2 < date3 and date2 is null),
        date2,
        date3)) as dateEarliest
FROM tbl;
```

This will work if your blanks are NULL.